# 12 Days Of Christmas C Program

Tags: c++, c

So I tried coding 12 days of Christmas by myself. I'm not yet done though with the lyrics, I'm still trying to figure out. But I don't understand why my "1st day" of Christmas gets doubled and partnered with a different gift and on the 12th day, no gift is showing up. I checked on my switch case and they seem to be right I guess. And is it possible that I could lessen my code to print out the complete lyrics?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() // Main Function
{
    int days, counter, num;
    //int counter = 1;  

    printf("\t\t***TWELVE DAYS OF CHRISTMAS***\n");
    printf("\t\t______________________________\n\n\n");

    for (counter=0; counter<=12; counter++)
    {   
        // counter++;
        switch(counter)
        {
            case 1: printf("\t\tA Partridge in a Pear Tree\n");break; // Day 12
            case 2: printf("\t\tTwo Turtle Doves\n"); break;
            case 3: printf("\t\tThree French Hens\n"); break;
            case 4: printf("\t\tFour Calling Birds \n"); break;
            case 5: printf("\t\tFive Golden Rings\n"); break;
            case 6: printf("\t\tSix Geese a Laying\n"); break;
            case 7: printf("\t\tSeven Swans a Swimming\n"); break;
            case 8: printf("\t\tEight Maids a Milking\n"); break;
            case 9: printf("\t\tNine Ladies Dancing\n"); break;
            case 10: printf("\t\tTen Lords a Leaping\n"); break;
            case 11: printf("\t\tEleven Pipers Piping\n"); break;
            case 12: printf("\t\tTwelve Drummers Drumming\n"); break; // Day 1 
        }
        printf("\n\tOn the ");

        switch(counter){
            case 1:
                printf("1st");
                break;  
            case 2: 
                printf("2nd");
                break;
            case 3: 
                printf("3rd");
                break;
            case 4: 
                printf("4th");
                break;
            case 5: 
                printf("5th");
                break;      
            case 6: 
                printf("6th");
                break;
            case 7: 
                printf("7th");
                break;
            case 8: 
                printf("8th");
                break;  
            case 9: 
                printf("9th");
                break;
            case 10:    
                printf("10th");
                break;  
            case 11:    
                printf("11th");
                break;  
            case 12:    
                printf("12th");
                break;                                                                                      
                default: 
                printf("1st", num);
                break;
            }
            printf(" day of Christmas my true love sent to me\n");

        }   

        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

And the instructions says, "Your function will just be invoked in the main() function and will not return anything" So does it mean that I will not make more functions? Or should I place all of my codes inside the main function only? Or create separate codes?

Comment: **Notice:** Your for loop goes from `0...12` but you have cases from `1...12`

Comment: It means, instead of your logic in the main function. Wrap it in another function (e.g. PrintTwelveDaysOfChristmas()) and the return type of that function is a void (no result). Then you can call that function from the main function.

Comment: You initialize `counter` to 0 in the beginning of the loop. But in the switch, you expect it to start from 1. Also, you print out the "partridge in a pear tree" part *before* "on the nth day of...") :)

Comment: If you turn your first switch upside down, and leave out the `break`s, you will get something interesting.

Comment: Here is a little trick that may make this a little easier: You know you want to start at one index in the switch statement and go all the way to "One Partridge in a Pear Tree" without breaking.  You could flip your switch statement and remove all the `break`'s (i.e.: start at case 12: and end at case 1:) ... then all you'd have to do is tell your program where the "entry point" is and it'll slide through all the remaining days.

Comment: As far as a computer is concerned, 0 means 1st, 1 means 2nd, and etc. because of how it counts. It's well worth baring that in mind and avoiding using crazy indices other than what the computer naturally talks in.

Comment: In addition to the above, surly you want to reverse the order of the `case` statements and remove all `break`'s

Comment: You can create an array of strings with something like `const char* presents[]={"Partridge", "Dove", "Hen", "Bird", "Ring"};` . Now you can make your code much more compact and readable.

Comment: "Your function will just be invoked in the main() function and will not return anything," sounds like they want you to write it in a separate function...

Comment: @Floris: Doesn't really work with the song, the lyrics are slightly less orderly than you seem to think.

Comment: @Veltas - I was showing how to create a string array; in the space of a comment I was not going to give the full strings, but it was my expectation that the OP could figure that out.

Comment: @Floris: I see, please excuse me. As for using arrays I completely agree, see below for my answer as I don't think that using a switch statement here is actually the best way of doing this. No matter how starved for a good switch exploit the programmers in this question may be!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into the switch statement again, and remember that breaks are not completely necessary.

```
switch (day) {
  case 2: printf("two turtle doves ");
  case 1: printf("and a partridge in a pear tree");
}
```

This will have the "day 2" start at "two turtle doves" and *fall through* to "and a partridge in a pear tree".

Meanwhile, the "day 1" starts are "and a partridge in a pear tree".

Comment: I'd instead recommend use of an array, and also to use [0, 12) rather than [1, 12].

Comment: @Veltas I would argue that that would make the code harder to understand, and it would be an unnecessary change.

Comment: @KirkBackus Then you would argue that a switch statement is a mini-anti-pattern.  It is a valid argument.  I try to avoid them myself; however, when they are called for (and this might be the rare case where they really are called for), they are best used properly.

Comment: Actually it is as simple to understand for someone who knows C, and it seems learning C properly is the aim of the asker. It's an unnecessary change but it's better style, no? I'd have thought the asker would rather learn decent programming than how to hack 12-days together the easiest way.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I forgot to add the whom I was talking to bit, I actually like the switch statement way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have `case 2` be `printf ("two turtle doves and ")`, instead of having the `"and"` in `case 1`?

Comment: Yes, that would be an improvement.

Answer (score 6):

I don't actually think a switch is the best choice here. We have a list of items to display that we can easily stick in an array and order, and we have to show different lists of these items each time. Although the switch syntax is nice here (as mentioned in the comments to the question, not as used in the asker's code itself), I think that simple loops are more appropriate than constantly asking the program to perform switch jumps.

This is my suggested solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char
  *presents[] = {
    "\t\tA Partridge in a Pear Tree\n", "\t\tTwo Turtle Doves\n",
    "\t\tThree French Hens\n", "\t\tFour Calling Birds \n",
    "\t\tFive Golden Rings\n", "\t\tSix Geese a Laying\n",
    "\t\tSeven Swans a Swimming\n", "\t\tEight Maids a Milking\n",
    "\t\tNine Ladies Dancing\n", "\t\tTen Lords a Leaping\n",
    "\t\tEleven Pipers Piping\n", "\t\tTwelve Drummers Drumming\n"},
  *days[] = {
    "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th",
    "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th"};

void printTwelveDaysSong(void)
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
    printf("\n\tOn the %s day of Christmas my true love sent to me\n", days[i]);
    for (j = i; j > 0; --j) fputs(presents[j], stdout);
    if (i > 0) fputs("\t\tand\n", stdout);
    fputs(presents[0], stdout);
  }
}

/* Example main function */
int main(void)
{
  printTwelveDaysSong();
  return 0;
}
```

I stuck the core code in a different function because it sounds like that's what's required, so I've shown that as well, nothing too special about that.

In the code I've used only C Standard Library functions for output, and I haven't attempted to implement an interactive program, you can add that yourself if you wish.

Comment: This is almost verbatim what I had in mind when I made my original comment about an array of strings. +1 for mindreading!

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop sets `counter` to zero, but your `switch` statement handles cases greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly you set counter to zero, the 1st switch prints nothing, the 2nd prints "On the 1st...".

Then you set counter to one...

Also you rather oddly print out the gift before you say which day it is.

To reduce the code, you should consider that for 1 to 12, only 1st, 2nd and 3rd don't end in th, and furthermore remember you can fall through cases in a switch (not particularly good style but works well for this sort of thing).

Comment: How should I do the "%dth" ? @Tom Tanner

Comment: @JennicaPrincess:  `printf("%dth", counter);` should work, if you make `counter` loop from 1 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

The for condition should be:

```
for (counter=1; counter<=12; counter++)
```

Comment: I'd instead recommend use of an array, and also to use [0, 12) rather than [1, 12].

Comment: I tried this but the "Patridge in a pear tree" comes first before the "On the first day..." why is that? @MatteoD

Comment: Our class did not tackle yet on arrays. We're still on basics, loops, and functions. I think I'll be having a hard time if I would use arrays because I still don't know it. @Veltes

Comment: @JennicaPrincess: Because that's the order you're printing stuff in.  You print the presents before the "On the Nth day...".  As it stands, with `counter` starting at 0, the first line most likely reads "On the day of Christmas...", doesn't it?  (Actually, never mind that; i just reread the code and noticed the default case.  But it does mean that you're printing `1st` both when counter == 0, and when counter == 1.)

Comment: @JennicaPrincess: Okay but I should warn you this is a site where people come to learn, not to be helped with H/W (although you could get help with H/W incidentally). Prepare to learn a thing or two when you come here.

Answer (score 0):

You start your for-loop from `counter=0`. This causes the first `switch` to print nothing and the second `switch` to go to `default` which prints "1st". That's probably why your first day is printed twice!

Change your for-loop to `for (counter = 1; counter <= 12; counter++)` instead!

Comment: You'd have to do more than this.  Otherwise, the first iteration would print `"\t\tA Partridge in a Pear Tree\n\tOn the 1st day of Christmas"`.

Comment: Yes, it seems a little odd to print the present first... The order of the `switch` statements has to be swapped too! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() // Main Function
{
int days, counter, num;
//int counter = 1;  

printf("\t\t***TWELVE DAYS OF CHRISTMAS***\n");
printf("\t\t______________________________\n\n\n");

for (counter=1; counter<=13; counter++)
{   
    printf("\n\tOn the ");

    switch(counter){
        case 1:
            printf("1st");
            break;  
        case 2: 
            printf("2nd");
            break;
        case 3: 
            printf("3rd");
            break;                                                             
        default: 
            printf(counter + "th");
            break;
        }

    printf(" day of Christmas my true love sent to me\n");
    for (int x= counter; x > 0; x--)
    {
        switch(x)
        {
            case 1: printf("\t\t");if (counter > 1 ) printf("And ");printf("A Partridge in a Pear Tree\n");break; // Day 12
            case 2: printf("\t\tTwo Turtle Doves\n"); break;
            case 3: printf("\t\tThree French Hens\n"); break;
            case 4: printf("\t\tFour Calling Birds \n"); break;
            case 5: printf("\t\tFive Golden Rings\n"); break;
            case 6: printf("\t\tSix Geese a Laying\n"); break;
            case 7: printf("\t\tSeven Swans a Swimming\n"); break;
            case 8: printf("\t\tEight Maids a Milking\n"); break;
            case 9: printf("\t\tNine Ladies Dancing\n"); break;
            case 10: printf("\t\tTen Lords a Leaping\n"); break;
            case 11: printf("\t\tEleven Pipers Piping\n"); break;
            case 12: printf("\t\tTwelve Drummers Drumming\n"); break; // Day 1 
        }
    }

}           
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps re-write the second switch so that the for loop becomes unecessary?  i.e. remove the breaks and write the cases upside-down. Not that I think switch statements are appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your professor's goal here was to teach you how to use switch statements(possibly requiring you to use multiple switch statements?). Obviously this program serves no practical purpose other than teaching. So all the people recommending you various "creative" ways of doing this (like using arrays and other things) are misunderstanding your situation. You made a few mistakes - and had a few unnecessary things in there. But you were on the right track and just needed to review it a few times (a particularly good notice coming from SuvP in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;

const char *num_day[] = {"-", "First", "Second", "Third",
         "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh",
         "Eighth", "Ninth", "Tenth", "Eleventh", "Twelfth"};
int main()
{

    for (int day = 1; day <= 12; ++day) {
    cout << "On the " << num_day[day]
         << " day of Christmas, my true love gave to me:\n";
    switch (day) {
        case 12: cout << "Twelve Drummers Drumming\n";
        case 11: cout << "Eleven Pipers Piping\n";
        case 10: cout << "Ten Lords a-Leaping\n";
        case 9: cout << "Nine Ladies Dancing\n";
        case 8: cout << "Eight Maids a-Milking\n";
        case 7: cout << "Seven Swans a-Swimming\n";
        case 6: cout << "Six Geese a-Laying\n";
        case 5: cout << "Five Gold Rings\n";
        case 4: cout << "Four Calling Birds\n";
        case 3: cout << "Three French Hens\n";
        case 2: cout << "Two Turtle Doves, and\n";
        case 1: cout << "A Partridge in a Pear Tree\n\n";
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Because of the missing `break` = fall-through this code doesn't give the correct result.